# How can I get a UIAlertAction handler to execute before the UIAlertController is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I want to call a segue from a UIAlertAction, but the handler does not execute until the UIAlertController is finished dismissing.

```
let editMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Edit", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let myAction = UIAlertAction(title: "My Action", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("some_segue", sender: self)

        })
editMenu.addAction(myAction)
self.presentViewController(editMenu, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

I would like the handler to execute immediately.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK just write it after you show/present the Alert as the thread won't wait for it come back:

```
// Create the controller
let editMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Edit", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
// Create an action for the controller with no handler
let myAction = UIAlertAction(title: "My Action", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
// Add the action to the controller
editMenu.addAction(myAction)

// show the controller/Alert to the user
self.presentViewController(editMenu, animated: false, completion: nil)

// As the above calls won't wait for the user these lines will be executed immediately
tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("some_segue", sender: self)
```

Hope that helps